# How would I make this happen with my preloader in JQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, preloader, preloading

As of now I have a very basic preloader set up.

```
$(window).load(function() {  

$("#status").fadeOut(); 

$("#preloader").delay(300).fadeOut("slow"); 

});
```

I've placed it on every page of my website I'm creating.

What I want to do is, have the preloader ONLY appear once for each page for each visit or for however long my website is cached in their browser.

For instance a person would view the website, then if they came back to the site the preloader wouldn't show because most of the website is already cached and would eliminate the purpose of a preloader.

Anyone have any ideas on how to make this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're already using a PHP session, you can stop inserting the HTML/CSS and jQuery if `$_SESSION['cached']` or similar is set.

Comment: What does your preloader do? Does it actually preload everything (in which case you should shove it way offscreen), or is it just annoying (in which case you should just take it out)?

Comment: If the external resources on the page is cached in the browser, window.onload would fire much sooner, so why do you need to remove it. If you where to remove it completely, I'd tend to agree, as it does seem like bad UX to let the user wait for the window to load, and then another 0.3 seconds, and then 0.6 seconds for the fracking thing to fade out, and I left a second ago.

Comment: @mooseman I'm not using any PHP sessions. Strictly a static HTML site.

Comment: @minitech - The preloader is a large screen with my logo in the middle that covers the entire page. Then when everything is loaded it fades out. The only problem is on every page it's going to show up every single time, regardless if most of the elements are cached. I like the effect but it might get annoying for people to see the fade in every single time.

Comment: @adeneo - It fades out pretty quickly when everything is cached but I don't know if people would get annoyed with it. Should I make there not be a delay at all? Or try to do my original idea?

Comment: This should be trivial to accomplish with local- or sessionStorage.

Comment: Just don’t do that, then. That’s not a preloader, that’s an annoying splash screen that everybody hates.